# How to show the child div on mouse hover of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a number of parent divs (.parent_div), which each contain a child div (.hotqcontent) where I output data from my database using a loop.

The following is my current markup:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="parent_div">
    <div class="hotqcontent">
      content of first div goes here...
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="parent_div">
    <div class="hotqcontent">
      content of second div goes here...
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="parent_div">
    <div class="hotqcontent">
      content of third div goes here...
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="parent_div">
    <div class="hotqcontent">
      content of fourth div goes here...
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve is when a user hovers / mouseovers a parent div, the contents of the child div contained within should be revealed.

To achieve this I wrote the following jQuery script but it doesn't appear to be working. It's not even showing the alert!

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.parent_div').hover(function() {
      alert("hello");
      $('.hotqcontent').toggle();
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

How can I modify or replace my existing code to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want pure CSS than you can do it like this....

In the CSS below, on initialization/page load, I am hiding child element using `display: none;` and then on `hover` of the parent element, say having a `class` `parent_div`, I use `display: block;` to unhide the element.

```
.hotqcontent {
   display: none;
   /* I assume you'll need display: none; on initialization */ 
}

.parent_div:hover .hotqcontent { 
   /* This selector will apply styles to hotqcontent when parent_div will be hovered */
   display: block;
   /* Other styles goes here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HXHF2/)

Comment: This is probably the better approach since it's a representation issue. Moreover, this is not susceptible to issues like the DOM state by design.

Comment: I tested, but its not showing the `hotqcontent` div on mouse over the parent div. Why? Please help

Comment: you are very helpful and kind person. As a human being this is very important. I assume people who reads this comment also help other developer likewise.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent_div').hover(function() { 
    alert("hello");
    $(this).find('.hotqcontent').toggle(); 
  });
});
```

Or

```
$(function() {
  $('.parent_div').hover(function() { 
    alert("hello");
    $(this).find('.hotqcontent').toggle(); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use css for this,

```
.parent_div:hover .hotqcontent {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with pure css (I've added a couple of bits in just to make it a bit neater for the JSFIDDLE):

```
.parent_div {
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.parent_div .hotqcontent {
    display: none;
}

.parent_div:hover .hotqcontent {
    display:block;
}
```

This will ensure that your site still functions in the same way if users have Javascript disabled.

Demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/LDchj/

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `document.ready` function inside `document.ready`..

try this

```
  $(function() {  //<--this is shorthand for document.ready
        $('.parent_div').hover(function() { 
             alert("hello");
             $(this).find('.hotqcontent').toggle(); 
             //or
            $(this).children().toggle(); 
       });
    });
```

**and yes your code will toggle all div with class `hotqcontent`..(which i think you don't need this) anyways if you want to toggle that particular div then use `this` reference to toggle that particular div**

**updated**

you can use on delegated event for dynamically generated elements

```
$(function() {  //<--this is shorthand for document.ready
        $('.content').on('mouseenter','.parent_div',function() { 
             alert("hello");
             $(this).find('.hotqcontent').toggle(); 
             //or
            $(this).children().toggle(); 
       });
    });
```

Comment: I tried but its not giving  an alert also on mouse over the parent div . i am using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.parent_div').on('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).children('.hotqcontent').show();
    }).on('mouseout',function(){
        $(this).children('.hotqcontent').hide();
    });;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wbvuG/)

Answer (score 1):

With `.hotqcontent` you are selecting every element with this class. But you want to select only the `.hotqcontent` element underneath the parent.

```
$('.hotqcontent', this).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("div.hotqcontent").css('display','none');
  jQuery("div.parent_div").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).children("div.hotqcontent").show(200);
    }, function(){
        jQuery(this).children("div.hotqcontent").hide(200);
    });
  });
});
```