# make child element visible and accesible on parent hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

What i have here is a share icon that should display other icons (facebook, g+, pinterest etc) when i hover over it. Thing is i need the social icons to be taken out of the page while they or the share icon are not hovered and i need them to fade in when they are being displayed. I have done this before, but i really have no ideea how exactly i did it. I want to learn the method of doing this since i will have to do it every now and then. How is this properly, simply and cleanly done?

HTML

```
<div class="share">
    <i class="fa fa-share">
        <span class="socials">
            <a class="pinterest" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i> </a>
            <a class="gplus" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> </a>
            <a class="twitter" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> </a>
            <a class="facebook" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </a>
        </span>
    </i>

    <div>Share</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.blog-wrapper .stats i.fa{
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.blog-wrapper .stats .share {
    position: relative;    
}

.blog-wrapper .stats .socials{
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: -20px;
    width: 35px;
    transition: 0.35s;    
    z-index: 100;    
}

.blog-wrapper .stats .socials a {
    margin: 0;
}
```

this is irelevant. the problem is more complex, as i described. what i know until now is

- using display:none takes the element out of the page layout
- using display:none cancels the transitions
  problem: i need to take out the element from the layout AND still have the transition
- i also need the child element not to show when hover is over them, only to show when hover is over the parent AND keep showing once they have been shown if the hover is on them

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the child div on mouse hover of parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479642/how-to-show-the-child-div-on-mouse-hover-of-parent-div)

Comment: yes, that i know too. but i need it to fade in using css transition

Comment: It seems that you copy-pasted the wrong chink of css in your question. Please edit it, or better- create a jsfiddle with where you got, It'll be much easier to help you from there.

Comment: @SzekelyJonathan http://jsfiddle.net/HXHF2/1/ , I've taken this demo from the answer I've posted on the question I shared the link with

Comment: i added extra description in the original question