# Show div upon hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a div like a menu upon hovering an text box but for some reason it is not showing up .

Here is my css

```
     .search:hover  #search_drop {
    display:block;
 }


     #search_drop {
        display:none;
        height:500px;
        width:500px;
        background:#000;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
     }
```

here is the html

```
     <div id="navigation_s" style="float:left">
       <ul >
         <li > 
           <div class="search">
             <div id="search_drop"> test </div>
              <form action="" id="searchform">
               <input type="text" name="search" id="searchbox" placeholder="looking for something?"/>
               <input type="submit" id="searchbutton" value="go"/>
              </form>
           </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

All I want to do is on hovering over search the #search_drop should be shown but it is not happening

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/B7m9j/

Comment: your html is incomplete, (</li>)
Work fine, be careful with your html, a missing </li> might be at the origin of your bug in some browser, try it there http://jsfiddle.net/RBSFJ/

Comment: And for some reason if you need any info over this than http://stackoverflow.com/a/16479686/1542290 my answer....

Comment: use javascript onmouseover="" to trigger an event that toggles the visibility... this would allow you to call it from the .search element.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hover on a non-displayed node.
`display:none` -> It is not on your page. So, you cannot hover on this. same applies for hidden
But, we can alter other properties. For example,

```
#search {
 border : 1px green solid;
}
#search:hover {
 border : 5px red solid;
}

<div id="search">
abcdefgh
abcdefgh
abcdefgh
</div>
```