# How to hide / show icon with :hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is exactly what I want to do
[image]

And this is my code

```
img.info-societe {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
img.info-societe:hover {
    display: inline;
}
```

Why doesn't it work? What's the best solution?

Comment: Please be clear with the question

Comment: Could you replicate in JSFiddle and CodePen

Comment: what about your current result ?

Comment: how the `:hover` will work when the element is not visible give `:hover` to the parent then the icon will be visible on `:hover`

Comment: @Vitorino but the icon on the <th> and i can do some event on th

Comment: should be like this `.parent(class name or id) img.info-societe {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}`  `.parent(class name or id):hover img.info-societe {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the child div on mouse hover of parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479642/how-to-show-the-child-div-on-mouse-hover-of-parent-div)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr img.info-societe {
  display: none;
}

tr:hover img.info-societe {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This fits with the advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479642/how-to-show-the-child-div-on-mouse-hover-of-parent-div

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `opacity` property instead of display.

```
img.info-societe {
   cursor: pointer;
   opacity: 0;
}
img.info-societe:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: if `opacity` is `0` then the user should know where the `element` is placed to `hover` on it so that it becomes `visible`

Comment: This answer is better for me, since with display my text left of the icon (which I make visibile/invisible) gets pushed to the left as soon as my icon appears.